# syntax error on function definition

Tags: function, class, animation

I'm exploring animation with python and I'm facing a problem with my code which is shown bellow. I get a "Syntax error" in the "test_visualize()" function definition at the end of the code.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
```

I define a class here, the objects of this class will be used in a simulation.

```
class Particle:
    def __init__(self, x, y, ang_speed):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.ang_speed = ang_speed
```

The following are the rules under which the particles evolve.

```
class ParticleSimulator:
    def __init__(self, particles):
        self.particles = particles
    def evolve(self, dt):
        timestep = 0.00001
        nsteps = int(dt/timestep)
        for i in range(nsteps):
            for p in self.particles:

                norm = (p.x**2 + p.y**2)**0.5
                v_x = (-p.y)/norm
                v_y = p.x/norm

                d_x = timestep * p.ang_speed * v_x
                d_y = timestep * p.ang_speed * v_y
                p.x += d_x
                p.y += d_y
```

Now I want to make an animation of my particles, so I define a new function.

```
def visualize(simulator):
    X = [p.x for p in simulator.particles]
    Y = [p.y for p in simulator.particles]
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = plt.subplot(111, aspect='equal')
    line, = ax.plot(X, Y, 'ro')

    plt.xlim(-1, 1)
    plt.ylim(-1, 1)


    def init():
        line.set_data([], [])
        return line,
    def animate(i):

        simulator.evolve(0.01)
        X = [p.x for p in simulator.particles]
        Y = [p.y for p in simulator.particles]
        line.set_data(X, Y)
        return line,

        anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

And finally, at the beginning of this block I get a Syntax Error. The idea of the following code is to test my visualization function. The strange thing is that the error belongs to the "def" line.

```
def test_visualize():
    particles = [Particle( 0.3, 0.5, +1), Particle( 0.0, -0.5, -1)]
    simulator = ParticleSimulator(particles)
    visualize(simulator)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_visualize()
```

Well guys thank you for your time!!!

Hope we can figure out this problem.

Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly, I do not get the same error.

The error you are receiving tells that the compiler did not expect to find a `def` on that line. It may have something to do with indentations. I copy your code here but now correctly indented:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

class Particle:
    def __init__(self, x, y, ang_speed):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.ang_speed = ang_speed

class ParticleSimulator:
    def __init__(self, particles):
        self.particles = particles
    def evolve(self, dt):
        timestep = 0.00001
        nsteps = int(dt/timestep)
        for i in range(nsteps):
            for p in self.particles:

                norm = (p.x**2 + p.y**2)**0.5
                v_x = (-p.y)/norm
                v_y = p.x/norm

                d_x = timestep * p.ang_speed * v_x
                d_y = timestep * p.ang_speed * v_y
                p.x += d_x
                p.y += d_y

def visualize(simulator):
    X = [p.x for p in simulator.particles]
    Y = [p.y for p in simulator.particles]
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = plt.subplot(111, aspect='equal')
    line, = ax.plot(X, Y, 'ro')

    plt.xlim(-1, 1)
    plt.ylim(-1, 1)


    def init():
        line.set_data([], [])
        return line,

    def animate(i):
        simulator.evolve(0.01)
        X = [p.x for p in simulator.particles]
        Y = [p.y for p in simulator.particles]
        line.set_data(X, Y)
        return line,

    anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, blit=False)
    plt.show()

def test_visualize():
    particles = [Particle( 0.3, 0.5, +1), Particle( 0.0, -0.5, -1)]
    simulator = ParticleSimulator(particles)
    visualize(simulator)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_visualize()
```

The only significant changes were fixing the odd indentations at the end of `visualize`. This works in my computer without a `SyntaxError`, now I see two interesting particles dance about. (Note that I changed `blit=False`, as setting it `True` breaks at least some Mac backends.)

If you cannot make it work, please copy and paste the code from above into your editor. A very typical reason for obscure errors is confusion between spaces and tabs in indentation or invisible characters in code.

Once you have it working, I suggest you expose it to the kind ladies and gentlemen of http://codereview.stackexchange.com. Your code is not bad at all, but there are a few stylistic things which might benefit from a bit of polishing!